# Magento 2.3.4 - How to install Inventory Management Manually?

Tags: magento2.3.4, msi, github

I am trying to install https://www.appjetty.com/magento2-magemob-inventory.htm, After installed the module during **di:compile** command i am getting the following error,

> Class Magento\Inventory\Model\Source does not exist   Class
> Biztech\Inventorysystementerprise\Controller\Mobileassistantpro\Product\addNewProduct\Interceptor
> generation error: The requested class did not generate prop   erly,
> because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only. If ---
> after running the 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the
> 'generated' directory    permission is set to write --- the requested
> class did not generate properly, then you must add the generated class
> object to the signature of the related constru   ct method, only. Nov
> 9, 2020

I am installed my Magento using GitHub installation, Inventory files missing **app/code/magento** path, how to install manually.
Source: https://devdocs.magento.com/extensions/inventory-management/

Comment: did you try `chmod 777` command on generated folder?

Comment: Yes, but same error

Answer (score 1):

You can get the missing Magento Inventory (a.k.a MSI) packages from: https://github.com/magento/inventory

For Magento 2.3.x you need to get the [latest 1.1.x release](https://github.com/magento/inventory/releases).

copy all module folders to `app/code/Magento` and run:

```
php bin/magento s:up
```

Comment: For my clarity, all the files move to app/code/magento, right?

Comment: Yes, i've updated my answer; Please upvote if it helps!

Comment: Column definition "order_id" and reference column definition "entity_id" are different in tables "inventory_pickup_location_order" and "sales_order"
Column definition "order_id" and reference column definition "entity_id" are different in tables "inventory_order_notification" and "sales_order"
Column definition "address_id" and reference column definition "address_id" are different in tables "inventory_pickup_location_quote_address" and "quote_address"

Comment: what is the error mean?

Comment: Shall i upload latest one?

Comment: Sorry, according to https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/inventory/release-notes.html you should use version 1.1.6 for Magento 2.3: https://github.com/magento/inventory/releases/tag/1.1.6